# Django rendering a specific block inside a modal and keep base-page active

Tags: jquery, django, modal-dialog, render

Is it possible to render a block of content inside a modal (jQuery-ui dialog box) with a child html page without reloading the whole base-page and breaking it's current active state?

I've tried to simply extend the base.html in the child pages but it seems to break the states of the base-page (maps, scripts). Seems like jQuery doesn't even follow to the child pages...

I want the base-page to stay the same, just open up a modal that gets some new content from the database via a child-page and the base to stay the same in the background.

Comment: Very easy, use fancybox

Comment: Gracias Victor! I will check it out! But i think it's more of the solution on how to implement it in Django that is the problem. Jquery Dialog works fine but the problem is that the child pages don't seem to inherit the scripts "state" or "mode" of the base. I have a map there and the current mapview and markers needs to be where they are when i open a modal with child-html content. Not reload the whole base with the new child. I sure it's a newbie mistake but im going crazy on this one..

Comment: It's easy, with fancybox you only use an ajax call or use the child html passed as a jquery's selector to fancybox

Comment: Ok. Yes. It seems like Ajax/Jquery is the only way to do this.. I was really trying to avoid it and do it the first way Django/HTML as described in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426806/can-a-django-view-be-displayed-in-a-lightbox/18427109#18427109